# UnsupportedClassVersionError while using Jmockit in a Java 1.5 Project

Tags: java, eclipse, junit4, jmockit, java-5

I am trying to use JMockit in a JUnit test, but I am getting an UnsupportedClassVersionError while running the tests from Eclipse. This is a Java 1.5 project and I have JDK 1.5.0.22 in build path and the version of JUnit in class path is 4.11 (downloaded from maven repository)

```
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: Bad version number in .class file
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:621)
   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:124)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:260)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:56)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:195)
   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:307)
   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:268)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:252)
   at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.loadClassAndCallPremain(InstrumentationImpl.java:133)
```

I went through the JMockit installation instructions and made the following changes;

1. Have jmockit.jar before Junit.jar in the classpath
2. Pass the jmockit.jar as an initialization parameter to the JVM
3. Project uses the JRE from a JDK installation instead of a "plain" JRE

[image: Eclipse Project specific Java Compiler Settings]

[image: Run config for Project]

I have spent lot of hours trying to fix this :(, but no luck. Please let me know if you have an solution for this? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't specified what version of JMockit you are using; however it seems to me like you're running into this:

```
From this version on, JMockit requires Java 6 or newer when running tests;
JRE 1.5 is no longer supported. Note that this only applies to the JRE/JDK
used for test  execution; class files compiled  for older versions of Java
are still supported.
```

That's [as of JMockit 1.8](http://jmockit.github.io/changes.html), released last April.

This, BTW, is to be expected, since Java 1.5 hasn't been publicly supported in over five years.

Comment: Thanks @dcsohl . Your answer helped me solve this issue. I was using Jmockit 1.14, so I just replaced JDK 5 on the build path with JRE 6 and now the JUnit along with JMockit works great. A big relief after a day struggle. Looks like I headed in the wrong directions initially looking at all those articles which specified the workarounds to make Jmockit work with Java 1.5- but it never did. Was it specified anywhere in JMockit web page / readme / installation doc that its not supported for Java 1.5 - Did I miss it ?

Comment: It wasn't highlighted; I had to go digging for it. It's mentioned on the changes page only, which I linked to above ("as of JMockit 1.8").